# How does gas pressure increase the lifespan of Halogen tungsten lamps in the Halogen Cycle?

Tags: visible-light, physical-chemistry, blackbody

I am curious about this passage "Since quartz is very strong, the gas pressure can be higher,[5] which reduces the rate of evaporation of the filament, permitting it to run a higher temperature (and so luminous efficacy) for the same average life." from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_lamp).

- I'm unclear if pressure or the Halogen Cycle equally facilitates
  greater longevity or if one has a dominant effect.

This passage in the Wikipedia article under the Halogen Cycle confused me, "At moderate temperatures the halogen reacts with the evaporating tungsten, the halide formed being moved around in the inert gas filling. At some point, however, it will reach higher temperature regions within the bulb where it then dissociates, releasing tungsten back onto the filament and freeing the halogen to repeat the process."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tungsten filaments are hot. They very slowly evaporate. Atoms of tungsten come flying off the hot surface and stick to the cold envelope of the bulb. Eventually the bulb darkens.

Also eventually a spot on the filament gets thin. The same current flows through the thin spot. So this spot gets hotter than the rest of the filament. This increases the rate of evaporation at the thin spot. The thin spot gets thinner until the filament breaks.

A halogen can be added to the bulb to prevent this. Halogens are elements in the right hand column of the table of elements - F, Cl, etc. These are very reactive. Lighter ones are more reactive. Typically They form bonds with tungsten, making $WF_6$, a gas, or $WCl_6$, a solid. Typically Cl is used in bulbs.

Even though $WCl_6$ is solid at room temperature, it has a low boiling point, 346.7 C. At temperatures inside a bulb, it evaporates fast enough to keep the bulb clean. This eats tungsten off the surface and cleans the bulb.

It also corrodes the surface of the filament when the bulb is off. However, when the bulb is on, another property of $WCl_6$ becomes important - it breaks down to W + CL at high temperatures.

The only place in the bulb hot enough to do this is the surface of the filament. So $WCl_6$ conveniently breaks down at just the right place to deposit tungsten back on the filament.

Furthermore, the thin spots are the hottest. Breakdown is faster there. The thin spots thicken. This extends the lifetime of the bulb.

The point about pressure is that higher pressure means more Cl is in the bulb. This increases the reaction rate.